# Python regex to find all strings that start with ' and end with '.tr ignoring leading and trailing whitespaces

Tags: python, regex, python-re

I am struggling to get the correct `regex` for my script. I would like to find all `Substrings` in a `file` that start with a `'` and end with `'.tr`. And save all these matches in a list.

This is what Ive got so far:

```
import glob
import pathlib
import re
       
libPathString = str(pathlib.Path.cwd().parent.resolve()) 

for path in glob.glob(libPathString + "/**", recursive=True):
    if(".dart" in path):
        with open(path, 'r+', encoding="utf-8") as file:
            data = [line.strip() for line in file.readlines()]
            data = ''.join(data)
            words = re.findall(r'\'.*\'.tr', data)
            print(words)
```

The first problem is that `words` is not just the matching substring but the whole file until the substring.

Also it is giving me this file:

```
  child: Hero(
    tag: heroTag ?? '',  // <- because of this and the line below starts with `tr`
    transitionOnUserGestures: true,
    child: Material(
```

But this **should not** match!

And then it is not finding this:

```
  AutoSizeText(
      'Das ist ein langer Text, der immer in einer Zeile ist.'
          .tr,
      style: AppTextStyles.montserratH4Regular,
```

This one **should match**!

What am I missing here?

Comment: Try `words = re.findall(r"'[^'\\]*(?:\\.[^'\\]*)*'\s*\.tr\b", data)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```py
words = re.findall(r"'[^'\\]*(?:\\.[^'\\]*)*'\s*\.tr\b", data)
```

See the [Python demo](https://ideone.com/YNJxbQ). *Details*:

- `'[^'\\]*(?:\\.[^'\\]*)*'` - `'`, zero or more chars other than `'` and `\`, and then zero or more sequences of a `\` followed with any single char and any zero or more chars other than `'` and `\` (this will match strings between `'` chars with any escaped chars in between)
- `\s*` - zero or more whitespaces (this will match any whitespace, including line breaks)
- `\.tr` - `.tr` string (note the escaped `.` that now matches a litera dot)
- `\b` - word boundary.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this

```regex
\s*'(.+?)'\s*\.tr
```

---

However, it looks like your use is to extract the string to be translated from a `.dart` file. I think it would be more elegant to use a library that can parse the AST of the dart language for this purpose.